# kubernetes nginx ingress Request Header Or Cookie Too Large

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

My nginx-ingress-controller is in the `ingress-nginx` namespace and I've set the large-client-header-buffers to `4 16k`, `4 32k` etc.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx  
data:
  proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
  large-client-header-buffers: "4 16k"
```

When I inspect the configuration in the nginx-controller pod I see:

```
 kubectl exec -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller-65fd579494-jptxh cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep large_client_header
        large_client_header_buffers     4 16k;
```

So everything seems to be configured correctly, still I get the error message `400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large`

Comment: Are you sure the nginx is returning the 400, and not the upstream app? Please do consider including the illustrative error message from the logs

Comment: What's your app says? What's in nginx logs?

Comment: could you fix this issue? I am having a same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [dedicated topic on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/319) about the problem. You can find there possible solutions. This problem should be completely removed based on [this issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/20901).

Look also at more tutorials how can you solve this problem, but from the browser site:

- [How to Fix the “Request Header Or Cookie Too Large” Issue [MiniTool News]](https://www.minitool.com/news/request-header-or-cookie-too-large.html)
- [400 Bad Request Request Header Or Cookie Too Large nginx - What does this error mean?](https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/918154)
- [HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1327416).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every nginx/ingress the request passed through should contain the config

- ingress : add 'large_client_header_buffers' in config
- nginx: add 'http2_max_header_size' 'http2_max_field_size' in nginx config

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#large-client-header-buffers

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_header_size
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_v2_module.html#http2_max_field_size